# Alexa device status "stuck in progress" and not coming out

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I attached my Amazon Echo Dot device into Alexa for Business.

Initially, status was "Synced". But, when I added this device into given room, it entered into state "Sync in progress", and stuck in that state only.

Required information-

1. Device software version - 597464620
2. Address in Room profile - Mexico City/New York (Tried with Area)
3. Alexa for Business Region - us-east-1 (N. Verginia)
4. My location - Bengalore, India
5. Device Name - Amazon Echo Dot.

Found one forum discussion over this, but didn't get much help - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=824543&tstart=0

Please help me out here.

Comment: It think it will not work in India as Alexa for Business is only supported in USA right now.

Comment: Known issue; Amazon is supposed to be working on a solution.  Check out [this post](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/2479/49) over on IoT; it may get more attention.